# Does 'pandas' replace function have a problem handling large dictionary objects?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with over 50k rows and wanted to replace the values of a datetime column with just the date. The original value has the format "01-Jun-2015 00:00:00", so I made the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = "my/file/path.csv"
csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath)
datetimes = csv_file["Date"]
replace_dates = {}
for datetime in datetimes:
  split_datetime = datetime.split()
  if(len(split_datetime) == 1): continue
  replace_dates[str(datetime)] = split_datetime[0]

csv_file["Date"].replace(replace_dates, inplace=True)
csv_file.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

But that code was raising the following exception:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'
```

I checked the data types of all the keys and values of the dictionary I was sending to the replace function and they were all strings (class 'str'), the dictionary looked like this:

```
{
  '01-Jun-2015 00:00:00': '01-Jun-2015',
  '01-Jun-2015 00:10:00': '01-Jun-2015',
  '01-Jun-2015 00:20:00': '01-Jun-2015'
}
```

Then I tried making a single value replacement in the python shell and it worked, so I changed my code to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
filepath = "my/file/path.csv"
csv_file = pd.read_csv(filepath)
datetimes = csv_file["Date"]
for datetime in datetimes:
  split_datetime = datetime.split()
  if(len(split_datetime) == 1): continue
  csv_file["Date"].replace({
    str(datetime): split_datetime[0]
  }, inplace=True)

csv_file.to_csv(filepath, index=False)
```

And now it works, but the problem is that I don't understand why this code works but the previous didn't. As far as I can tell, the only difference is that instead of storing all the values in a dictionary and executing the replace function once, I'm now executing the replace function once for every single value, which I don't really like. I'm new to pandas so I don't know if I was doing something wrong while creating the dictionary or if it was too large (aroung 50k values don't sound too large to me, to be honest), any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
csv_file['Date'] = csv_file['Date'].apply(lambda dt: dt.split()[0])
```